# Random Pareto distribution in R with 30% of values being <= specified amount

Tags: r

Let me begin by saying this is a class assignment for an intro to R course.

First, in VGAM why are there dparetoI, ParetoI, pparetoI, qparetoI & rparetoI?
Are they not the same things?

My problem:
I would like to generate 50 random numbers in a pareto distribution.
I would like the range to be 1 – 60 but I also need to have 30% of the values <= 4.

Using VGAM I have tried a variety of functions and combinations of pareto from what I could find in documentation as well as a few things online.

I experimented with fit, quantiles and forcing a sequence from examples I found but I'm new and didn't make much sense of it.

I’ve been using this:

```
alpha <- 1   # location 
k <- 2 # shape     
mySteps <- rpareto(50,alpha,k)
range(mySteps)
str(mySteps[mySteps <= 4])
```

After enough iterations, the range will be acceptable but entries <= 4 are never close.

So my questions are:

Am I using the right pareto function? 
If not, can you point me in the right direction?
If so, do I just keep running it until the “right” data comes up?

Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: what level of stats do you know? This follows the same structure as the other distributions in r. `rnorm` generates random normals, `dnorm` for the density, `runinf` and `dunif` are the same for the uniform distribution, so yes, `rpareto` is the right one for random numbers draw from the Pareto distribution

Comment: I took stats a very long time ago and it feels like I'm starting over. Thanks. Good to know I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So reading the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) for Pareto Distribution, you can see that the CDF of the Pareto distribution is given by:

> F<sub>X</sub>(x) = 1 - (x<sub>m</sub>/x)<sup>α</sup>

The CDF gives the probability that X (your random variable) < x (a given value). You want Pareto distributions where

> Prob(X < 4) ≡ F<sub>X</sub>(4) = 0.3

or

> 0.3 = 1 - (x<sub>m</sub>/4)<sup>α</sup>

This defines a relation between x<sub>m</sub> and α

> x<sub>m</sub> = 4 * (0.7)<sup>1/α</sup>

In R code:

```
library(VGAM)
set.seed(1)
alpha <- 1
k     <- 4 * (0.7)^(1/alpha)
X     <- rpareto(50,k,alpha)
quantile(X,0.3)   # confirm that 30% are < 4
#      30% 
# 3.891941
```

Plot the histogram and the distribution

```
hist(X, breaks=c(1:60,Inf),xlim=c(1,60))
x <- 1:60
lines(x,dpareto(x,k,alpha), col="red")
```

[image]

If you repeat this process for different alpha, you will get different distribution functions, but in all cases ~30% of the sample will be < 4. The reason it is only approximately 30% is that you have a finite sample size (50).

Comment: Thanks! That will take me a while to digest.