# How to create a "random-pareto" in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo, prng

Since I am not well-versed in mathematics, I am struggling with the implementation of a random number generator in NetLogo which follows roughly a pareto distribution. This is the follow-up question of this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212700/how-to-add-power-law-likelihood-to-netlogo-model), where I would like to substitue the `random-float` with something like `"random-pareto"` in order to have events taking place in the model following a pareto distribution (thinking of simulated earthquakes and their degree of destructiveness).

The code in question is:

```
  ask hits [
     let %draw (random-float 100)
     let %strength 0  ;; no damage
     if (%draw < 50) [set %strength (%strength + 1)]  ;;1 for little damage
     if (%draw < 10) [set %strength (%strength + 1)]  ;;2 for middle damage
     if (%draw < 5) [set %strength (%strength + 1)]  ;;3 for strong damage
     if (%draw < 1) [set %strength (%strength + 1)]  ;;4 for complete destruction

     ifelse pcolor = red [die]
     [ ask n-of %strength patches [ set pcolor red ]]
   ]
```

I got inspired by this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792380/random-pareto-distribution-in-r-with-30-of-values-being-specified-amount) to do the same in R and the Netlogo Dictionary [here](http://file:///home/sebastian/NetLogo/docs/dict/random-exponential.html) about the fact that `random-exponential` can be written as `(- mean) * ln random-float 1.0`.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the equation to convert from a uniform distribution (random-float) to the distribution you want. This might be a better question for the stackexchange stats. However, according to Wikipedia, the formula is:

$$
T = \frac{m}{U^\frac{1}{\alpha}}
$$

where $U$ is the uniform input, $T$ is the Pareto distributed random number, $m$ (minimum) and $\alpha$ are parameters of the distribution. If this is correct, you could code in NetLogo as

```
to-report random-pareto [alpha mm]
  report mm / ( random-float 1 ^ (1 / alpha) )
end
```

Say you wanted a random Pareto from the distribution with minimum of 1 and alpha of 3, you could then get one with the code `random-pareto 3 1`

Comment: looks like there's no maths markdown on stackexchange!

Comment: Thank you very much, JenB. Now I understand better how to "transliterate" a formula into NetLogo.

Comment: is there a way to have a max value for this formula, like `random` netlogo command has?

Comment: If you want to have a truncated distribution, use a while loop and keep generating a random value until it falls within the limits you want. If this is not enough explanation, please ask a separate question (which is what you really should do anyway).